# Automatic Picture Capture on PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I am trying to build an app with PhoneGap and Android and was wondering if anyone knows how to  have an app automatically capture a picture, say 5 seconds after the user opens the app, without the user actually pressing anything.  Any help would be apprciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you can do a setTimeout in you on "deviceready" event handler to call navigator.camera.getPicture() but there is no way to automate the clicking of the button. The user will need to do that. Other than that you'd need to write a plugin to automatically take the picture if that is what you really need.

Comment: Yeah, but you'd have to write your own UI for taking a picture in Android. It would be a bit of a pain IMHO.