# App to take picture on time interval

Tags: javascript, cordova, appmobi

I need to create an app that with Appmobi or Phonegap that will be able to take an automatic picture with a time interval.

Is it possible to perform this?

I know hot to launch the camera with 30 seconds interval, but I need to launch the camera and take a picture. The device will be on a quadcopter, so no human interaction will be avalilable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603797/automatic-picture-capture-on-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [***camera.getPicture***](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function getPicture(){
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 }); 
}

setInterval(getPicture, 30000);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code do not automate the user click action on camera's button. I need to take pictures without user's interaction with a 30 seconds interval.

Comment: @IkerVázquez This cannot be automated due to restrictions on devices. Imagine the security risks if this were possible.

Answer (score -1):

yes that is a automated one..with help of setInterval method the picture will taken for every 3 seconds..